# Why is my evaporative cooler rattling?

Tags: cooling, evaporative-cooling

I have a brand new evaporative cooler. It was great for a month, until it started making a rattling noise. We found a bolt  behind the bearing that fell out and glued it in. This only temporarily solved the issue, as the cooler now consistently rattles. Upon investigation, the squirrel cage seems to move back and forth very easily and doesn’t seem to be mounted. I believe this is making the rattling noise.

What could this possibly be? Is this something that can be fixed if it is not mounted properly?

[image: slack]

[image: slack]

Comment: that would be a warranty call

Comment: Say that again, you glued the bolt ?

Comment: Clarification- I just used Loctite thread locker so it wouldn’t vibrate out of place again.

Comment: That is not a new unit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As I said, it’s a month old, so no it does not look brand new. But it was brand new.

Comment: I would say it is a refurbished unit based on amount of deposits on the wires. But if you say it is new, way are you here. Call for WARRANTY service. The more you do to it, the higher the risk of voided warranty.

Comment: There was nothing on the wires when I bought it, I just live in the woods surrounded by dirt. I’m here to get an actual answer is anyone knows what the issue is, they won’t come out and fix it I just have to completely remove it and take it in for a brand new unit and due to the size of my property it’s a huge event to remove it by myself, take it back, get a new unit, and install a new one.

Comment: Then the decision is clear. Fix the vibration your self, while you might loose warranty. For one you do not use loctite to hold screws and bolts, use proper washers for that. If it is vibrating to much it might need warranty repair to get the fan balanced.